# How can I force default DNS query to work in TCP mode?

Tags: macos, network, dns

In China, the so-called GFW often contaminates DNS results like

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 archive.org 

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;archive.org.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
archive.org.        2662    IN  A   159.106.121.75
```

Here `159.106.121.75` is a fake IP. We have to use the TCP mode for DNS query:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 +tcp archive.org

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;archive.org.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
archive.org.        237 IN  A   207.241.224.2
```

Now we get the real IP `207.241.224.2`.

In <kbd>System Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>Network</kbd>, the <kbd>Advanced...</kbd> button can open a tab for setting DNS. However, I can only add the IP addresses of DNS servers but cannot do anything else. So my question is: **how can I force the default DNS query working in the TCP mode?**

**PS**: I don't want to modify the `/etc/hosts` file to circumvent this problem as it's inconvenient. If there's any elegant method that can solve this problem, it will save me much time :) Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to force the mDNSResponder to use TCP instead of UDP.

I've found a workaround though. The method outlined below uses a local DNS-proxy ([dnschef](https://thesprawl.org/projects/dnschef/)) forced to use TCP for outgoing DNS-requests.

- Download and unzip [dnschef-0.3](https://thesprawl.org/media/projects/dnschef-0.3.zip).
- Download and unzip [dnslib](https://bitbucket.org/paulc/dnslib/get/04713cc4a9df.zip)
- Download and unarchive [IPy-0.76](http://cheeseshop.python.org/packages/source/I/IPy/IPy-0.76.tar.gz)
- `cd` to the *dnslib* folder:

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads/paulc-dnslib-04713cc4a9df
  ```
- install *dnslib*:

  ```
  sudo python ./setup.py install
  ```
- `cd` to the *IPy* folder:

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads/IPy-0.76
  ```
- install *IPy*:

  ```
  sudo python ./setup.py install
  ```
- Open System Preferences -> Network, replace your current DNS-server(s) (e.g. 8.8.8.8/8.8.8.4) by a local one with the IP 127.0.0.1 and apply the changes.
- `cd` to the *dnschef* folder and start it:

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads/dnschef-0.3 
  sudo ./dnschef.py --nameservers 8.8.8.8#53#tcp
  ```

If the last command is too troublesome or ugly (well, it is ugly because you have to open Terminal.app and start the DNS-proxy), you can move the dnschef.py and .ini to another path and create a launch daemon to start the DNS-proxy while booting.

Example:

- `sudo mkdir /usr/local/python`
- `sudo cp ~/Downloads/dnschef-0.3/dns* /usr/local/python/`
- `sudo rm /usr/local/python/dnschef.exe`
- `sudo touch /Library/LaunchDaemon/local.dnschef.plist`
- copy and paste the following content into the newly created file with an appropriate editor
  (e.g `sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemon/local.dnschef.plist`):

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
      <key>Label</key>
      <string>local.dnschef</string>
      <key>ProgramArguments</key>
      <array>
          <string>/usr/local/python/dnschef.py</string>
          <string>--nameservers</string>
          <string>8.8.8.8#53#tcp</string>
      </array>
      <key>RunAtLoad</key>
      <true/>
  </dict>
  </plist>
  ```
- Load the file with `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.dnschef.plist`

  All files and folders created must be owned by root:wheel.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I'm pretty sure you'll need quotes around `8.8.8.8#53#tcp` (in the interactive start version; the .plist file looks fine as it is).

Comment: @GordonDavisson I've tested it and quotes (i.e "8.8.8.8#53#tcp")  break the launch daemon. The `sudo ./dnschef.py --nameservers 8.8.8.8#53#tcp` command works.

Comment: Right. Quotes are needed interactively to keep the shell from interpreting `#` as a comment marker; launchd doesn't use a shell so quotes are not needed there (and will, as you say, break it because there's no shell to remove them).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Haven't tried it yet but I completely believe it works :D

Comment: Updated link for dnschef: https://github.com/iphelix/dnschef